# css footer content did not show properly in html5

Tags: css, html

This is my code for footer section:

```
<footer>
         <div class="footer">
            <nav>
               <ul class="nav-list1">
                  <li><img src="img/article-logo.png"  alt="img"/></li>
                  <li><a href="#">ARTICLES</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">BLOG</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">COLUMN</li>
                  <li><a href="#">TOPICS</li>
               </ul>
               <ul class="nav-list2">
                  <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">AUTHOURS</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">MASTHEAD</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">CONTRIBUTE</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">STYLEGUIDE</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">SPONSORSHIPS</a></li>
               </ul>
            </nav>
            <hr class="hr-style" />
           <section class="clearfix footerWidth">
               <div class="footer-column1">
                  <img src="img/footer1.png" class="footer-image" alt="dot"/> 
                  <p class="footer-title-1">.NET Training</p>
                  <p class="footer-pgf">If you have a .NET question on a topic that 's not covered by other more specific forums.</p>
                  <p><a class="footer-link" href="#">ask here. ></a></p> 
               </div>
               <div class="footer-column2">
                  <img src="img/footer2.png" class="footer-image" alt="expert"/> 
                  <p class="footer-title-2">Shopify Expert</p>
                  <p class="footer-pgf">Unique custom made Shopify theme and tweaks.</p>
                  <p><a class="footer-link" href="#">click to view</a></p>
               </div>
            </section>
            <hr class="hr-style" />
            <p class="copyright">Copyright &copy; 2013 Dot Net How</p>
         </div>
      </footer>
```

This is my JSfiddle what i tried:

http://jsfiddle.net/u89q6cyz/

Now my page look this:
http://s13.postimg.org/js23ca6nr/Untitled_1_copy.png

Now i need to display the footer-content as i marked in my image in the right side of the image.

I tried all possible ways.. I don't know how to fix..

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do two modification in your CSS code.

1. Remove the margin-left on the following class.

   ```
   .footer-column2 
   {
     /*margin-left: 112px !important;*/
    }
   ```
2. Add width:50% for your footer columns.

   ```
   .footer-column1,.footer-column2
    {
     float:left;
     width:50%;
    }
   ```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/u89q6cyz/1/)

Comment: If you add little bit more content, it will come in two lines.

Comment: if you want to use only these text and in two lines means, add like this `.footer-column2{width:46%}`